# Memory Warning Whenever Saving To iPhone Photo Album from UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, uiimagepickercontroller

I am working on an application that allows the user to take pictures by tapping on the screen. Whenever they tap, it calls the UIImagePickerController's 'takePicture' method. Then, in the delegate controller, in the 'didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo' method, I do:

```
UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
```

Every time that I do this, even if the taps are far apart, I receive a memory warning. The application is not crashing, but I would like to optimize performance if possible. I know that this should be allowed because the built in camera does this on its own and saves to the photo album every time as well.

I don't really care about optimized quality necessarily, so would resizing the images first help with the issue?

Comment: That's to be expected with the size of the images the camera takes. Don't worry, this won't impact performance, as the extra memory is cleared soon enough.

Comment: @duci9y Thanks for the response. Is it worth requiring one picture to be completely saved before allowing the user to take another, or would the memory still be okay if multiple pictures were to be taken rapidly?

Comment: Chill. It will be okay. Don't worry about anything unless your app actually crashes.